# upload and retrieve images to database in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**index.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>upload images</title>
</head>
<body> 
<form action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<input name="uploadedimage" type="file">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>

<?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }
     if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "images/".$imagename;

if(isset($tmp_name)){
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path)) {

    $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES 

('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload ==".mysql_error());  

}else{

   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**mysqlconnect.php:**

```
<?php
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/
$host="localhost";
$databasename="karma";
$user="root";
$pass="";
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if($conn)
{
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($databasename, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
}
else
{
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

When i run this above script, there is no errors displayed. and no image didn't contain in database.

May i know how to upload and retrieve images from database?

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: *"When i run this above script, there is no errors displayed"* - Are you checking for them? If not, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Which the above **WILL** throw you an error, because you're not checking for errors and you're treating your table and columns as such; remove the quotes.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: sorry for my mistake.. but before that i run, that time it doesn't shoe any error.. can you fixed out this issue?

Comment: `INSERT into images_tbl (images_path,submission_date)` and not `INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date')` as I've already outlined above.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: now  also, got no error, but nothing to happen.. no image in database..

Comment: Check DB table, column names etc, or ask the guy who gave you answer. I've told you what the basic problem was. People who give "**answers**", should be able to back it with actual solutions to your code, instead of tutorials-to.

Comment: I found your problem. Change all instances of `$tmp_name` to `$temp_name` and put this line `$query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (images_path,submission_date) VALUES 

('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";` inside an unbroken/single line, otherwise it will throw an error. Such as `$query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (images_path,submission_date) VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems that are causing your code to fail are the following:

Change all instances of `$tmp_name` in your code to `$temp_name`

This being for `if(isset($tmp_name))` and `if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path))`

Since you are using `$temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];`, therefore you are using the wrong variable, which is (*by the way*) undefined.

Also, as stated previously in the comments area; this line:

```
INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date')
```

When referencing tables and columns, quotes are not to be used. Either wrap them in backticks, or remove them.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` (`column1`,`column2`)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO tablename (column1,column2)
```

Backticks are mostly used to safeguard against using reserved words, or if there happens to be a space between words used, or if a hyphen is used as a word seperator. (*Just a quick FYI sidenote*).

For a list of those reserved words, visit the MySQL.com website:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

**Developer tips:**

Using proper error reporting is vital during development.

Adding the following to the top of your file(s) will help signal any errors, if any are found:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Finally:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Examples can be found inside those pages.